# Is on/before 15 July better than by 15 July if I want to be precise and unambiguous? Which is the more common form?

Tags: british-english, ambiguity, dates, range-inclusion

When the last day of registration is, let's say, 15 July, we currently say "please confirm your registration *before* 16 July" but students often send their confirmation on 16 July, rather than 15. I guess it's the date itself that's misleading.

Comment: You should say "on or before 15 July". Completely unambiguous, at the cost of two extra two-letter words.

Comment: **Which is the more common form?** What I've seen in many applications is like "register by September 15, 2012".

Comment: @its_me: "*register by Sept. 15*" implies that registrations can still be made on the 15th.  *On or before* is quite common and, in the business world especially, both "*on or before*" and "*by close-of-business (often abbreviated as COB) on*" are frequently used.

Comment: Simpler to say "... no later than 15 July."

Comment: This question can be improved by providing citations for references you consulted before posting the question. Consulting references and reporting the result is basic site etiquette.

Answer (score 2):

As in the comments, a common form that is succinct yet unambiguous is:

> Please confirm your registration *no later than 15 July*.

Another unambiguous option is:

> Please confirm your registration *on or before 15 July*.