# Is "to" inclusive in “I worked at company X from April 2012 to April 2013”?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage, semantics, dates, range-inclusion

I have a question about the use of the word *to* as a time proposition. Is *to* inclusive in the following sentence?

> I worked at company X from April 2012 to April 2013.

Comment: I read it as from April 1st to April 1st. Add the days or "end of " or "inclusive"

Comment: Strongly related to, and almost certainly a duplicate of one or more of the following: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/43926 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/38169 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/56335 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/111057 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16017 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/56335 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/96097 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/38169 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/80000 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/30927 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/83897

Comment: I would guess it means you stopped working there sometime after 12:01AM on April 1, but before (or at) 12:00PM on April 30.

Answer (score 1):

It's ambiguous.

Some may read it as including April 2013, others may not. I'd probably read it as inclusive.

American English uses the inclusive word *through*:

> - I worked at company X from April 2012 through April 2013.

For unambiguous British English, add extra wording:

> - I worked at company X from April 2012 to April 2013, inclusive.
> - I worked at company X from April 2012 through to April 2013.
> - I worked at company X from April 2012 up to and including April 2013.

Comment: What about the _to_ in "through to" ?

Comment: @mplungjan: American uses "through". British uses "to" but it's ambiguous so "through to" is a British compromise that doesn't sound too weird and American.

Comment: From a British perspective, it's not really necessary to add those extra wordings. They come across as unnecessarily formal and long-winded. It would be much simpler and more natural as *I worked at company X from April 2012 to April 2013* or *I worked at company X from April 2012 until April 2013*.