# Is "till" inclusive or exclusive?

Tags: american-english, british-english, mathematics, count

I just want to know whether till is exclusive or inclusive, like if someone says count from 1 till 5, should I say 1,2,3,4,5 or 1,23,4

Comment: From....to - is the right usage. "From...till' doesn't sound appropriate.  As for 'from 1 to 5, it includes both 1 and 5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "to" inclusive in “I worked at company X from April 2012 to April 2013”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112082/is-to-inclusive-in-i-worked-at-company-x-from-april-2012-to-april-2013) The 'from ... to ...' construction is inherently ambiguous, though some examples are resolved pragmatically ('count from 1 to 5' would be clear enough).

Comment: If someone says "Count from 1 till 5" I would think they were talking about four hours of counting.

Comment: @Robusto - I can count from 1 till 5 in about a second!